# Match everything until certain pattern

Tags: python, regex

So I have this piece of text..

```
200 g torskefilet
havsalt og friskkværnet peber
8 tynde skiver røget spæk
150 g rødbede (ca. 2 stk.)
½ dl blommeeddike
1 spsk. olivenolie
1 spsk. rørsukker
lidt rødbedeblade eller anden bitter salat

Vask rødbederne, kom dem i en gryde med vand, og bring dem i kog. Kog rødbederne i ca. 30 min., til de er møre, men stadig har lidt bid.

Kom koldt vand på rødbederne, så de køler lidt af, og ”gnid” skindet af efterfølgende, så du kommer ind til rødbedens silkebløde indre.

Skær rødbeder ud i grove tern, og kom dem i en gryde med eddike, sukker og olivenolie.

Lad eddiken koge ind i rødbederne, så de bliver glaserede, og lagen får konsistens som sirup.

Tjek torskefileterne for evt. vildfarne ben og for friskhed (de skal dufte af hav – ikke af havn!).

Skær torsken ud i helt små tern. Brug en skarp kniv, så kødet bliver skåret – ikke moset.

Kom torsketataren i en skål, krydr med salt og peber, og rør rundt.
Form tataren til 4 små bøffer, og sæt dem i køleskabet i 10 min., så tataren lige sætter sig inden den steges.

Varm en pande op, og steg de tynde skiver spæk, så de bliver sprøde og krøller lidt sammen. Tag spækket af panden, og læg det på et stykke køkkenrulle.
Hæld overskydende fedt af panden, og steg så tatarbøfferne i 30 sek. – bare på den ene side. På den måde får de en flot steges korpe, samtidig med at de stadig er rå.

Server bøfferne med de lune, glaserede rødbeder, det sprøde spæk, lidt salat og friskskrabet peberrods-sne (se næste opskrift).

Jeg elsker klassisk kogetorsk med hele svineriet: syltede rødbeder, spæk, høvlet peberrod, fiskesennep og smørsovs – og denne forret er min moderne variant af den evigtgode kombination.
```

Its a recipe text, the first half is the ingredients with their quantities and the second half is the steps. I'm trying to match using Regex the ingredients and the steps separately.

For ingredients I came up with this Regex string `^(\d|[a-z]).*(?=[A-Z].*)?$` and the for the steps I did this `^[A-Z].*`.

However the piece of text is part of a document with recipes each with their own ingredients and steps, so I want to identify each recipe separately. To do that I want to match the ingredients up until the first occurence of the steps pattern and the steps until the first occurence of the ingredients pattern.

How do I do that?

Comment: Hmm...not the downvoter, but maybe because that your question is either **too broad** or **unclear** (there's two close vote on your question). So what have you tried already? And what's the except output?

Comment: Awesome, I'll re-phrase my the question

Comment: does Vask means one in english?

Comment: No, it means "wash" in English. It's Danish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex:

```
 from itertools import imap
from itertools import takewhile, groupby

with open("recipes.txt") as f:
    grps = groupby(imap(str.rstrip, f), key=str.islower )
    for k, v in grps:
        if k:
            ing, steps = list(v), list(next(grps, ("", ""))[1])
            print(ing)
            print(steps)
            print("\n\n")
```

That will work regardless of spacing once the ingredients are always lowercase.

Input:

```
200 g torskefilet
havsalt og friskkværnet peber
8 tynde skiver røget spæk
150 g rødbede (ca. 2 stk.)
½ dl blommeeddike
1 spsk. olivenolie
1 spsk. rørsukker
lidt rødbedeblade eller anden bitter salat

Vask rødbederne, kom dem i en gryde med vand, og bring dem i kog. Kog rødbederne i ca. 30 min., til de er møre, men stadig har lidt bid.

Kom koldt vand på rødbederne, så de køler lidt af, og ”gnid” skindet af efterfølgende, så du kommer ind til rødbedens silkebløde indre.

Skær rødbeder ud i grove tern, og kom dem i en gryde med eddike, sukker og olivenolie.

Lad eddiken koge ind i rødbederne, så de bliver glaserede, og lagen får konsistens som sirup.

Tjek torskefileterne for evt. vildfarne ben og for friskhed (de skal dufte af hav – ikke af havn!).

Skær torsken ud i helt små tern. Brug en skarp kniv, så kødet bliver skåret – ikke moset.

Kom torsketataren i en skål, krydr med salt og peber, og rør rundt.
Form tataren til 4 små bøffer, og sæt dem i køleskabet i 10 min., så tataren lige sætter sig inden den steges.

Varm en pande op, og steg de tynde skiver spæk, så de bliver sprøde og krøller lidt sammen. Tag spækket af panden, og læg det på et stykke køkkenrulle.
Hæld overskydende fedt af panden, og steg så tatarbøfferne i 30 sek. – bare på den ene side. På den måde får de en flot steges korpe, samtidig med at de stadig er rå.

Server bøfferne med de lune, glaserede rødbeder, det sprøde spæk, lidt salat og friskskrabet peberrods-sne (se næste opskrift).

Jeg elsker klassisk kogetorsk med hele svineriet: syltede rødbeder, spæk, høvlet peberrod, fiskesennep og smørsovs – og denne forret er min moderne variant af den evigtgode kombination.
200 blah
400 bar
foobar bar

Foobar
Bar
```

Output:

```
['200 g torskefilet', 'havsalt og friskkv\xc3\xa6rnet peber', '8 tynde skiver r\xc3\xb8get sp\xc3\xa6k', '150 g r\xc3\xb8dbede (ca. 2 stk.)', '\xc2\xbd dl blommeeddike', '1 spsk. olivenolie', '1 spsk. r\xc3\xb8rsukker', 'lidt r\xc3\xb8dbedeblade eller anden bitter salat']
['', 'Vask r\xc3\xb8dbederne, kom dem i en gryde med vand, og bring dem i kog. Kog r\xc3\xb8dbederne i ca. 30 min., til de er m\xc3\xb8re, men stadig har lidt bid.', '', 'Kom koldt vand p\xc3\xa5 r\xc3\xb8dbederne, s\xc3\xa5 de k\xc3\xb8ler lidt af, og \xe2\x80\x9dgnid\xe2\x80\x9d skindet af efterf\xc3\xb8lgende, s\xc3\xa5 du kommer ind til r\xc3\xb8dbedens silkebl\xc3\xb8de indre.', '', 'Sk\xc3\xa6r r\xc3\xb8dbeder ud i grove tern, og kom dem i en gryde med eddike, sukker og olivenolie.', '', 'Lad eddiken koge ind i r\xc3\xb8dbederne, s\xc3\xa5 de bliver glaserede, og lagen f\xc3\xa5r konsistens som sirup.', '', 'Tjek torskefileterne for evt. vildfarne ben og for friskhed (de skal dufte af hav \xe2\x80\x93 ikke af havn!).', '', 'Sk\xc3\xa6r torsken ud i helt sm\xc3\xa5 tern. Brug en skarp kniv, s\xc3\xa5 k\xc3\xb8det bliver sk\xc3\xa5ret \xe2\x80\x93 ikke moset.', '', 'Kom torsketataren i en sk\xc3\xa5l, krydr med salt og peber, og r\xc3\xb8r rundt.', 'Form tataren til 4 sm\xc3\xa5 b\xc3\xb8ffer, og s\xc3\xa6t dem i k\xc3\xb8leskabet i 10 min., s\xc3\xa5 tataren lige s\xc3\xa6tter sig inden den steges.', '', 'Varm en pande op, og steg de tynde skiver sp\xc3\xa6k, s\xc3\xa5 de bliver spr\xc3\xb8de og kr\xc3\xb8ller lidt sammen. Tag sp\xc3\xa6kket af panden, og l\xc3\xa6g det p\xc3\xa5 et stykke k\xc3\xb8kkenrulle.', 'H\xc3\xa6ld overskydende fedt af panden, og steg s\xc3\xa5 tatarb\xc3\xb8fferne i 30 sek. \xe2\x80\x93 bare p\xc3\xa5 den ene side. P\xc3\xa5 den m\xc3\xa5de f\xc3\xa5r de en flot steges korpe, samtidig med at de stadig er r\xc3\xa5.', '', 'Server b\xc3\xb8fferne med de lune, glaserede r\xc3\xb8dbeder, det spr\xc3\xb8de sp\xc3\xa6k, lidt salat og friskskrabet peberrods-sne (se n\xc3\xa6ste opskrift).', '', 'Jeg elsker klassisk kogetorsk med hele svineriet: syltede r\xc3\xb8dbeder, sp\xc3\xa6k, h\xc3\xb8vlet peberrod, fiskesennep og sm\xc3\xb8rsovs \xe2\x80\x93 og denne forret er min moderne variant af den evigtgode kombination.']



['200 blah', '400 bar', 'foobar bar']
['', 'Foobar', 'Bar']
```

If you want to remove the empty lines:

```
 grps = groupby((line for line in imap(str.rstrip, f) if line), key=str.islower )
```

Which will remove any empty lines i.e:

```
['200 blah', '400 bar', 'foobar bar']
['Foobar', 'Bar']
```

Comment: The problem is if I have multiple recipes in that file, it'll jumble the results together.

Comment: Matching the ingredients until the steps, then wrapping those results together and moving to the next, I imagined that would be the best.

Comment: @Souljacker,  you can apply the logic using groupby, I will edit. What separates the next ingredients?

Comment: The ingredients are just specified by starting with either a number or a lower case character. Then the steps start with an uppercase character...

Comment: Like 'ingredients' 'steps' 'ingredients' 'steps', did I vaguely answer your question?

Comment: And always spaces between lines?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: I'm parsing this from xhtml to complicate things a bit more. Could I explain it to you in more depth through chat?

Comment: @Souljacker, add an example of how the next ingredients may start

Comment: 1 dl letmælk\nsukker\nsalt og friskkværnet peber ...

Comment: And that works like a charm, sir :)

Comment: @Souljacker, no worries, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the first empty line is between the ingredients and the steps, so you might not even need regex:

```
ingredients, steps = recipe_string.split("\n\n", 1)
```

This will split the string at the first instance of 2 consecutive newlines.

Comment: Or, similiar `ingredients, _, steps = recipe_string.partition('\n\n')`